# keep getting an error in terminal when doing php artisan october:up

Tags: php, laravel, terminal, octobercms

I am trying to install october cms and I am currently on the last step where I need to type `php artisan october:up` but when I do, I keep getting this error:

```
 [PDOException]                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

I added this: '`default' => 'mysql', // Default database connection` to config/database.php file.

here is the file:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | PDO Fetch Style
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By default, database results will be returned as instances of the PHP
    | stdClass object; however, you may desire to retrieve records in an
    | array format for simplicity. Here you can tweak the fetch style.
    |
    */

    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => 'mysql',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => 'storage/database.sqlite',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'port'      => '',
            'database'  => 'database',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => '',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => 'localhost',
            'port'     => '',
            'database' => 'database',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => 'localhost',
            'port'     => '',
            'database' => 'database',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk have not actually be run in the databases.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => [
            'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
            'port'     => 6379,
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

];
```

these are all the directions on how to install in the console

```
Console installation
The command-line interface (CLI) method of installation requires Composer to manage its dependencies.

Download the application source code by using create-project in your terminal. This will install to a directory called /myoctober:

composer create-project october/october myoctober dev-master
Once this task has finished, open the file config/database.php and set your database connection:

'default' => 'mysql', // Default database connection
Configure the connections section below it with the database credentials.

Next, run the CLI migration process, this will build the database tables:

php artisan october:up
You can sign in to the back-end area via the /backend route and using the default username admin and password admin.

You also may wish to inspect config/app.php and config/cms.php to change any optional configuration.
```

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set up your mysql configuration.

Currently its value is:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'port'      => '',
    'database'  => 'database',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
],
```

As a result PHP is trying to connect to mysql using the default socket (which in this case, does not exist, hence the "file does not exist" error from `PDO`). If you actually want to connect to `localhost` with user `root` and no password, I would suggest setting the port number to `3306`.